# How to remove blue underline under text in google chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

This only happens in Google chrome ,I am using chrome 17.0.928 version. This works fine in firefox , but blue underline in google chrome .

```
.thumbnail:hover{z-index: 50;text-decoration: none;position:relative;}
.thumbnail span{  position: absolute;background:#000;padding: 5px;left: -1000px;
 border: 0px solid #ddd;visibility: hidden;color: #fff;width:388px;height:190px;text-decoration: none;}
.thumbnail:hover span{ text-align:left;visibility: visible;top: 0;left: 110px;text- decoration:none; 
 top:-120px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #aaa; -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px   #aaa;box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #aaa;}
.hoverbold {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 11px;
color: #B09F6E;
} ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NW8Nw/3/

Comment: Blue underline does not show in Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m.

Comment: there is a blue line in safari 5.1.7 and chrome 17.0.928

Comment: What do your Chrome dev tools show? Do they show it's inheriting a border or text-decoration property from some other element?

Comment: What is wrong with the 3 answers below? Why don't you accept one?

Answer (score 3):

Very simple, actually. You have to style the link apart, I got rid of it with

```
.thumbnail a:link {
    text-decoration: none;       
}
```

you should do the same for `a:hover`, `a:visited` and `a:active`.

Edit:
And a whole lot later, I realized you could do it with only one selector:

```
.thumbnail a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the decoration for each state of the link

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
{text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
.thumbnail a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

On a side note, you have multiple `<div>`s within your `<a>` tag. `<a>` tags should only ever contain inline elements.

Comment: `A` tags have a transparent content model under the new HTML5 specs, which allows them in some cases to contain block level elements. From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#content-model, "The a element now has a transparent content model (except it does not allow interactive content descendants), meaning that it has the same content model as its parent. This means that the a element can now contain e.g. div elements, if its parent allows flow content."

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem and since I couldn't find a possible solution I did this.

```
div {
      text-decoration:underline;
      text-decoration-color:white;
    }
```

Here your text-decoration-color and background-color should be same thereby hiding the blue underline.
Hope this helps